# Is it possible to pass metadata to Stripe from Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2, stripe

With Craft 3 and Craft Commerce 2 with the P&T Stripe gateway is it possible to pass metadata to Stripe? I've tried various combinations of hidden fields but without success so far.

I was hoping something like this on the payment form might work.

```
<input type="hidden" name="metadata[foo]" value="bar">
```